# Paste excel graph into powerpoint on Mac

Tags: excel, macos, powerpoint, copy-paste

I have always been able to simply copy and paste excel graphs into powerpoint until today. I have tried copying the excel graph and then opening powerpoint --> paste special --> Microsoft Office Graphic Object which still doesn't work. I am able to paste the table of values from excel to powerpoint, it is just the graph causing a problem. I am also able to copy the graph and paste into other programs such as Word. I can then copy the graph from word and paste into powerpoint, doing this I noticed that when I used paste special, the source is listed as the Microsoft word. When I do this from powerpoint, no source is recognized. Any suggestions are appreciated.

See above, I have also ensured there are no updates and tried restarting multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the graph,  or chart, to update then use cmnd&shift%4 to get it as an image.

Then paste that, I convert the image to jpeg as it is smaller than png but it depends what you might need later.

Comment: I want to retain the ability to edit